# Gherkin test using table fails with error "Cannot read property 'bold' of undefined"

Tags: datatable, gherkin, codeceptjs

Using codeceptJs 2.1.1 with Gherkin 5.1.0  french test I'm trying to check all the fields are present in a form using a datable to provide fields name.

Here is the Gherkin test:

```
@tabletest
Scénario: Les champs
Alors je vois les champs :
| coteComplete   |
| typeOptionCote |
```

Here is the corresponding step:

```js
Then('je vois les champs( de saisie) :', (name) => {
  I.say('name', name);
  I.seeElement(`input[name=${name}], select[name=${name}], textearea[name=${name}]`);
});
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
$ npx codeceptjs run --grep "tabletest" --debug --verbose
CodeceptJS v2.1.1
Using test root "C:\PISTARD\diffusion\dev\pistard-diffusion"
Helpers: Protractor
Plugins: screenshotOnFail, wdio

Recherche par cote @PDIFF-56 --
    Emitted | suite.before ([object Object])
 » Started SeleniumStandaloneLauncher
 » [Session] Starting singleton browser session
  Les champs @tabletest
    Emitted | test.before ([object Object])
    Emitted | hook.start ([object Object])
    Emitted | step.before (I am on page "recherche-avancee")
    Emitted | step.after (I am on page "recherche-avancee")
    Emitted | step.start (I am on page "recherche-avancee")
    Etant donné que je suis sur la page "recherche avancee"
      I am on page "recherche-avancee"
      » Visited http://localhost:4200/recherche-avancee
    Emitted | step.passed (I am on page "recherche-avancee")
    Emitted | step.finish (I am on page "recherche-avancee")
    Emitted | hook.passed ([object Object])
    Emitted | test.start ([object Object])
    [1] Error | TypeError: Cannot read property 'bold' of undefined
    [1] Starting <teardown> session
    Emitted | test.failed ([object Object])
    Emitted | test.finish ([object Object])
    [1] <teardown> Stopping recording promises
 » <screenshotOnFail> Test failed, saving screenshot
 » Screenshot has been saved to C:\PISTARD\diffusion\dev\pistard-diffusion\codeceptjs-output\Les_champs_1557763592.failed.png
  × FAILED in 287ms

    [2] Starting recording promises
    Emitted | test.after ([object Object])
    Emitted | suite.after ([object Object])

-- FAILURES:

  1) Recherche par cote @PDIFF-56
       Les champs @tabletest:
     Cannot read property 'bold' of undefined
  ypeError: Cannot read property 'bold' of undefined
      at Object.say (node_modules\codeceptjs\lib\output.js:139:53)
      at recorder.add (node_modules\codeceptjs\lib\actor.js:40:78)
      at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)


  FAIL  | 0 passed, 1 failed   // 5s
    Emitted | global.result ([object Object])
    Emitted | global.after ([object Object])
 » Stopped SeleniumStandaloneLauncher
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using node inspector I was able to see further in the trace.
Add the argument `--node-arg=--inspect-brk` to tyou command

```sh
npx --node-arg=--inspect-brk codeceptjs run --grep "tabletest" --debug
```

Then open nodejsinspector from your chrome devtools by clicking the node icon:

[image]

As for the ***"bold of undefined"*** error it

```
I.say("InputName:" + name);
```

About the received variables I could see the test in fact receives an object containing the array of values and not actual value. The actual value is accessible like this:

```js
let name = dataTest.rows[0].cells[0].value
```

so you have to loop manually in the array you receive to get each value and test it

```js
Then('je vois les champs( de saisie)( :)', (dataTest) => {
  let name;
  dataTest.rows.forEach(element => {
    name = element.cells[0].value;
    I.seeElement(`input[name=${name}], select[name=${name}], textearea[name=${name}]`);
  });
  debugger;
});
```